# Is there any method in web3 through we can verify whether the nonce associated with any transaction or not of same from address?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nonce

How to get the new nonce of from address using web3? There shouldn't be any transaction associated with this. Is there any way to get this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the transaction count (nonce) of any address using `web3.eth.getTransactionCount('address')` as explained in [web3 documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactioncount)

Hope this helps

Comment: But this method won't give the correct transaction count, there may be possible that some transactions are already initiated but not gets complete. So, in this case, the count values would not be updated.

Comment: I do not understand what are you expecting to get, the function will give you the transaction count of the address at the current block. Other than that will be to predict the future.

Comment: @Shubham Most functions in web3 accept an extra argument with the target block. You can use 'pending' like this `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address, 'pending')` it will return the count including those pending transactions.